# IF Statement In View Not Triggering

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this code block in my controller (I know, db stuff should be in model..I'll transfer it over there once working). Searches the database for a "subscription" and echos in the view. That works. However, in my view, I want to add an IF statement like the second block of code below - but it's not working. Suggestions? In other words, how would you write the IF statement in the view? Pretty sure the `query` portion is incorrect...

```
    // displays current subscription in view
    $userid = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');

    $this -> db -> select('subscription');
    $this -> db -> where ('id', $userid);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('subscriptions');

    if($query -> result() == TRUE) // if subscription exists for user, display:
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data['packagename'] = $row->subscription;
        } 
    }
```

In view:

```
    <?php if($query -> result() == TRUE) : ?>
    <? echo $packagename; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Where do you pass your `$data` array to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on what I see from your code, I am getting the feeling that you think whatever variables you use in your controller are automatically available within your view.  This is not the case.  You should be setting your variables and performing your logic in the controller and passing what you want displayed to your view.

This is what your controller should look like:

```
// displays current subscription in view
$userid = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');

$this -> db -> select('subscription');
$this -> db -> where ('id', $userid);
$query = $this -> db -> get('subscriptions');

if($row = $query -> result()) // if subscription exists for user, display:
{
        $data['packagename'] = $row->subscription;
}

$this->load->view("yourview", $data);
```

You do not need a `foreach` as you are pulling by ID - you only want one record.

Then, in your view, just display it like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($packagename)) echo $packagename;?>
```

Comment: Hi Darrrrrren, this is exactly what I had before. But if the result is not true, I don't want to display anything at all in the view.

Comment: In that case, get rid of the `else` in the controller and output `<?php if (!empty($packagename)) echo $packagename;?>`

Comment: You should keep the database stuff in your models, not the controller.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am aware of that but I'm addressing this specific issue at hand, not giving a general lesson about MVC - feel free to do that in your own answer.

Comment: @MikeBarwick: Didn't see that part ^_^

Comment: What's the difference between your IF string and this one? `<?php if (isset($packagename)) echo $packagename; ?> `

Comment: @MikeBarwick : essentially nothing.  `empty` will additionally check to ensure it's set *and* not an empty string as well.  But your `if` is fine.

Answer (score 5):

`$query->result()` does not return a boolean, it returns an array ob objects.

To check if the query returned a result, use `num_rows()`.

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't pass your `$query` object to the view, instead use `isset` to see if the variable is there:

```
<?php if(isset($packagename)): ?>
    <?php echo $packagename; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep your DB logic out of your views, that is what models are for.  If you're already passing $packagename into your view, why not simply test for it?

```php
<?php if ( isset($packagename) ) : ?>
    <? echo $packagename; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or, if you can use short_open_tags:

```
<? if ( isset($packagename) ) : ?>
    <?= $packagename ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Don't use short open tags. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Simplest answer! Works like a charm!

Comment: Short open tags exist for a reason.  If you are unable to control or predict the PHP environment, then you should not use short open tags.  If you do control the server/environment, or the environment reliably supports short open tags, then why not use them.  PHP is a great template language if you combine short open tags with alternative syntax.  In any case, I suggested the NON short open tag version first, for this reason.